# How do I handle ToManyRedirects panicks in Rust?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I have a Rust project that use the "reqwest" crate and has the below function:

```
fn elem_html_vec(url: &String, element: &str, vec_elem: &mut Vec<String>) {
    let response: String = get(url)
        .expect("Could not load URL.")
        .text()
        .expect("Could not load text");
    let document: scraper::Html = scraper::Html::parse_document(&response);
    let parsed_elements: scraper::Selector = scraper::Selector::parse(element).unwrap();
    for elem in document.select(&parsed_elements) {
        vec_elem.push(elem.inner_html());
    }
}
```

But when I call the function and the "url" argument ("https://twitter.com/Lions") is a link to a web page that redirects you to another page, I get the below error message.

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: reqwest::Error { kind: Redirect, url: Url { scheme: "https", cannot_be_a_base: false, username: "", password: None, host: Some(Domain("twitter.com")), port: None, path: "/Lions", query: None, fragment: None }, source: TooManyRedirects }', src/main.rs:79:37
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I want it to get the date of the final page it redirects to. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`https://twitter.com/Lions` redirects to `https://twitter.com/i/flow/login?redirect_after_login=%2FLions` and also sets a cookie using the header `set-cookie: guest_id=...`. If you do not set the cookie on the redirected request then it redirects to the same location, giving you an infinite loop.

You need to configure `reqwest` to use cookies, possibly using the [`cookie_store`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.ClientBuilder.html#method.cookie_store) method. To do this, you'll need to replace the `reqwest::get` call with a `Client` created using a `ClientBuilder`.

Comment: I changed the first line of the function to "let client = Client::builder().build().unwrap();
    let response = client.get(url).send().unwrap().text().unwrap();", but I could not find in the docs how to configure reqwest to use cookies. All the docs mention using Jar which my project does not have.

Comment: Use `let client = Client::builder().cookie_store(true).build().unwrap()`. You will also need to set the feature `"cookies"` for the `reqwest` crate in `Cargo.toml`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using the "redirect" feature in "reqwest". Below is the code.

```
fn elem_html_vec(url: &String, element: &str, vec_elem: &mut Vec<String>) {
    let redirect_rules: redirect::Policy =
        reqwest::redirect::Policy::custom(|attempt: redirect::Attempt<'_>| {
            if attempt.previous().len() > 5 {
                attempt.stop()
            } else {
                attempt.follow()
            }
        });
    let client: Client = Client::builder().redirect(redirect_rules).build().unwrap();
    let response: String = client.get(url).send().unwrap().text().unwrap();
    let document: scraper::Html = scraper::Html::parse_document(&response);
    let parsed_elements: scraper::Selector = scraper::Selector::parse(element).unwrap();
    for elem in document.select(&parsed_elements) {
        vec_elem.push(elem.inner_html());
    }
}
```